# Which date is listed on overnight flight?

Tags: air-travel

If I'm flying overnight West Coast US to East Coast US, is the date on the ticket the date of departure or the date of arrival at the destination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date and time of the ticket is the departure time (the local time at the origin airport when the aircraft is meant to depart).

Answer (score 2):

Both departure and arrival date and time are the local dates and times. This applies for any travel, domestic and international, that crosses time zones.